# Is it possible to get a marker if you know it's id?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Does OpenLayers include a function to return a marker reference based on it's ID? This is the code snippet I want to work (I have labeled it with a comment that reads "HERE!"): I attempted to retrieve the marker using using the command "getMarkerById(this.id)" and firebug informed me that the returned value was undefined. Then I tried using the static id number of one of the markers ("41014") and that didnt work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$(function()
{
        var map, layer;


        //alert("RAN!!");

        map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
        {'layers':'basic'} );
        map.addLayer(wms);
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-40, 30), 2.5);
        var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
        map.addLayer(markers);


        //load and retrieve values from local XML file here
    var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://whxlab3.dart.ns.ec.gc.ca/~brinka/EMETsiteV1/buoys.xml");
    var z=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("id");
    var y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lat");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lng");

    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        //use loaded XML file to retrieve values for marker positions
        var px = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var py = y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var pz = z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var size = new OpenLayers.Size(32, 37);
        var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
        var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('stock_images/buoy.png', size, offset);
        icon.setOpacity(0.85);


        var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(px, py);

        var marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon);
        marker.id=(pz);

        marker.events.register("mouseover", marker, function(){
            console.log("Over the marker "+this.id+" at place "+this.lonlat);
            this.inflate(1.2);
            this.setOpacity(1);
        });

        marker.events.register("mouseout", marker, function(){
            console.log("Out the marker "+this.id+" at place "+this.lonlat);
            this.inflate(1/1.2);
            this.setOpacity(0.85);
        });
        marker.events.register("click", marker, function(){
            console.log("Clicked "+this.id+" at place "+this.lonlat);
            console.log("Z value here: ", this.id);
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", this.lonlat, new OpenLayers.Size(200, 200), ("Buoy Number: "+this.id), null, true);

            map.addPopup(popup);
            markers.removeMarker(getMarkerById(this.id)); //HERE!
        });

        markers.addMarker(marker);

    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

No,
but you can define a marker in a (global) object like:

```
obj.marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon);
```

than add to a marker layer (for instance "markers"):

```
markers.addMarker(obj.marker);
```

If you want to remove it, do:

```
markers.removeMarker(obj.marker);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        "OpenLayers WMS",
        "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
        {'layers':'basic'} );
        map.addLayer(wms);
        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-40, 30), 2.5);
```

Marker Layer Add (Vector)

```
 var markerlayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Marker Layers", { 
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    'default': {
                        externalGraphic: "stock_images/buoy.png",  
                        graphicWidth:32,//pixel
                        graphicHeight:37,//pixel
                        graphicOpacity:"${opacity}"
                    }
                })
            });
            map.addLayer(markerlayer); 

var xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("http://whxlab3.dart.ns.ec.gc.ca/~brinka/EMETsiteV1/buoys.xml");
    var z=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("id");
    var y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lat");
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lng");
```

for:

```
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++)
            {
        var px = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var py = y[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var pz = z[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

         var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(px, py);
        var marker= new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonlat.lon, lonlat.lat));
       // var marker= new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(px, py));
marker.attributes = {
        opacity: "1"
};
        markerlayer.addFeatures([marker]);
        };
```

click function

```
    markercontrol = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(markerlayer, { eventListeners: { featurehighlighted: controlfunction } }) 
    map.addControl(markercontrol);


    function controlfunction(e) {
        var featureID = e.feature.id;
var marker = markerlayer.getFeatureById(featureID)
marker.attributes.opacity = '0.5';//opacity
markerlayer.removeFeatures(marker);//remove
    console.log(featureID);
    console.log(e);
    }
```

and look at for hover : 
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.8/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html